# How to copy and add a prefix to a filename?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am new to progress 4GL. I use the below query but not sure how to add a prefix to a filename before copying to a new directory. It's a single-line query in the file and can be compiled using the progress compiler.

Note - Original file should be same as it is after renaming, copying.

```
define variable lvc_filename as character no-undo.
define variable lvc_newpath as character no-undo.

assign
    lvc_filename = '/mgeditmp/ast/wbxp.i'
    lvc_newpath  = '/mgeditmp/wbxp.i'
    .
unix silent value("cp -f " + lvc_filename + ' ' + lvc_newpath).
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `num-entries`, the `entry` statement and the `entry` function:

```
def var iparts as int  no-undo.
def var cold   as char no-undo initial '/dir/file'.
def var cnew   as char no-undo.

iparts = num-entries( cold, '/' ).
if iparts > 0 then
   assign 
      cnew = cold
      entry( iparts, cnew, '/' ) = 'prefix' + entry( iparts, cnew, '/' )
      .
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`OS-COPY`](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-reference-117/page/OS-COPY-statement.html) command. There's also an `OS-RENAME` command if you're in the same folder.